# Add a paragraph or table etc. at Cursor

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a function for adding the contents of a separate google document at the cursor point within the active document, but I haven't been able to get it to work. I keep getting the "Element does not contain the specified child element" exception, and then the contents gets pasted to the bottom of the document rather than at the cursor point!

```js
function AddTable() {
  //here you need to get document id from url (Example, 1oWyVMa-8fzQ4leCrn2kIk70GT5O9pqsXsT88ZjYE_z8)
  var FileTemplateFileId = "1MFG06knf__tcwHWdybaBk124Ia_Mb0gBE0Gk8e0URAM"; //Browser.inputBox("ID der Serienbriefvorlage (aus Dokumentenlink kopieren):");
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(FileTemplateFileId);
  var DocName = doc.getName();

  //Create copy of the template document and open it
  var docCopy = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var totalParagraphs = doc.getBody().getParagraphs(); // get the total number of paragraphs elements
  Logger.log(totalParagraphs);
  var cursor = docCopy.getCursor();
  var totalElements = doc.getNumChildren();
  var elements = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < totalElements; ++j) {
    var body = docCopy.getBody();
    var element = doc.getChild(j).copy();
    var type = element.getType();
    if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH) {
      body.appendParagraph(element);
    } else if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE) {
      body.appendTable(element);
    } else if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM) {
      body.appendListItem(element);
    }
    //    ...add other conditions (headers, footers...
  }
  Logger.log(element.editAsText().getText());
  elements.push(element); // store paragraphs in an array
  Logger.log(element.editAsText().getText());

  for (var el = 0; el < elements.length; el++) {
    var paragraph = elements[el].copy();
    
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var bodys = doc.getBody();
  var cursor = doc.getCursor();
  var element = cursor.getElement();
  var container = element.getParent();
  try {
    var childIndex = body.getChildIndex(container);
    bodys.insertParagraph(childIndex, paragraph);
  } catch (e) {
    DocumentApp.getUi().alert("There was a problem: " + e.message);
  }
  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to copy the objects (paragraphs, tables and lists) from the document of `1MFG06knf__tcwHWdybaBk124Ia_Mb0gBE0Gk8e0URAM` to the active Document.
- You want to copy the objects to the cursor position on the active Document.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `appendParagraph`, `appendTable` and `appendListItem` are used at the 1st for loop. I think that the reason that the copied objects are put to the last of the document is due to this.
- `var body = docCopy.getBody();` can be put to the out of the for loop.
- In your case, I think that when the 1st for loop is modified, 2nd for loop is not required.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function AddTable() {
  var FileTemplateFileId = "1MFG06knf__tcwHWdybaBk124Ia_Mb0gBE0Gk8e0URAM";
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(FileTemplateFileId);
  var docCopy = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = docCopy.getBody();
  var cursor = docCopy.getCursor();
  var cursorPos = docCopy.getBody().getChildIndex(cursor.getElement());
  var totalElements = doc.getNumChildren();
  for (var j = 0; j < totalElements; ++j) {
    var element = doc.getChild(j).copy();
    var type = element.getType();
    if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH) {
      body.insertParagraph(cursorPos + j, element);
    } else if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE) {
      body.insertTable(cursorPos + j, element);
    } else if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM) {
      body.insertListItem(cursorPos + j, element);
    }
  }
}
```

- It seems that `DocName` is not used in your script.

#### References:

- [insertParagraph()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#insertparagraphchildindex,-paragraph)
- [insertTable()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#inserttablechildindex,-table)
- [insertListItem()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#insertListItem(Integer,ListItem))

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize. At that time, can you provide the sample source Document? By this, I would like to confirm it.